# What would be the behavior if maxConnections is reached for netTcpbinding in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am wondering what would happen if a WCF service with binding 'netTcpBinding' and default maxConnections setting (10) would be listening to 100 clients exchanging with the service.

Would the soft hosting the service be high in memory ? (compared to a maxConnections > number of clients)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if the maximum number of connections to the server is 10 but there are 100 clients trying to connect to the server, only 10 clients will be connected to the server at the same time, and the other clients will wait until the previous client connection times out or disconnects.

Wcf will allow as many connections as possible depending on your server's hardware configuration.

Comment: thank for your answer but that does not really answer my question. Let me rephrase : if 10 max conn is allowed and 100 is trying to connect, I think there will be some impact on the soft hosting the service. My question is : what would be the impact ?
Or even impact on the network ?

Comment: Too many client connections may wait or even timeout out. The network bandwidth of the server is used up, and the server breaks down when the number of connections reaches a certain level.